# JavaScript Switch Statement is not executing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to calculate the difference of time. There is a start time and an end time. The time is in the form of a 12 hour clock format.

I made a switch statement that switches the PM time values to its 24 hour equivalent.

EX: 01:00:00pm  = 13:00:00

But when I print to the log the time is not changing.

This where I am stuck, any help is greatly appreciated.

```js
const startTime1 = document.getElementById("startTime").value;
const startStatus = document.getElementById("startStatus").value;
const endTime1  = document.getElementById("endTime").value;
const endStatus = document.getElementById("endStatus").value;
//creating dummy vars
console.log(startTime1, endTime1)
var startTime = startTime1
var endTime = endTime1

if (startStatus =='pm'){
    switch(startTime){
        case startTime =='01:00:00':
            startTime = '13:00:00'
            break;
        case startTime =='02:00:00':
            startTime = '14:00:00'
            break;
        case startTime ==='03:00:00':
            startTime = '15:00:00'
            break;    
        case startTime =='04:00:00':
            startTime = '16:00:00'
            break;     
        case startTime =='05:00:00':
            startTime = '17:00:00'
            break; 
        case startTime =='06:00:00':
            startTime = '18:00:00'
            break; 
        case startTime =='07:00:00':
            startTime = '19:00:00'
            break;
        case startTime =='08:00:00':
            startTime = '20:00:00'
            break;
        case startTime =='09:00:00':
            startTime = '21:00:00'
            break;    
        case startTime =='10:00:00':
            startTime = '22:00:00'
            break;     
        case startTime =='11:00:00':
            startTime = '23:00:00'
            break; 
        case startTime =='12':
            startTime = '24:00:00'
            break;                
    }

}
if (endStatus =='pm'){
    switch(endTime){
        case endTime =='01:00:00':
            endTime = '13:00:00'
            break;
        case endTime =='02:00:00':
            endTime = '14:00:00'
            break;
        case endTime =='03:00:00':
            endTime = '15:00:00'
            break;    
        case endTime =='04:00:00':
            endTime = '16:00:00'
            break;     
        case endTime =='05:00:00':
            endTime = '17:00:00'
            break; 
        case endTime =='06:00:00':
            endTime = '18:00:00'
            break; 
        case endTime =='07:00:00':
            endTime = '19:00:00'
            break;
        case endTime =='08:00:00':
            endTime = '20:00:00'
            break;
        case endTime =='09:00:00':
            endTime = '21:00:00'
            break;    
        case endTime =='10:00:00':
            endTime = '22:00:00'
            break;     
        case endTime =='11:00:00':
            endTime = '23:00:00'
            break; 
        case endTime =='12':
            endTime = '24:00:00'
            break;                
}
}


console.log(startTime + startStatus)
console.log(endTime + endStatus)
```

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, caption {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
.Headers{
text-align: center;
background-color: lightblue;
font-size: 2em;
}
.form{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.buttons{
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Workday Planner</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Headers">
    <h2>Workday Planner</h2>
    <h3>MAX 12 Hours</h3>
    </div>
    <form class="form">
        <label for="startTime">Start Time:</label>
        <select id ="startTime" >
            <optgroup label="Start Time">
                <option value="01:00:00">01:00</option>
                <option value="02:00:00">02:00</option>
                <option value="03:00:00">03:00</option>              
                <option value="04:00:00">04:00</option>
                <option value="05:00:00">05:00</option>
                <option value="06:00:00" selected>06:00</option>
                <option value="07:00:00">07:00</option>
                <option value="08:00:00">08:00</option>
                <option value="09:00:00">09:00</option>
                <option value="10:00:00">10:00</option>
                <option value="11:00:00">11:00</option>
                <option value="12:00:00">12:00</option>
            </optgroup>
          </select>
         <select id="startStatus">
             <option value="am" selected>am</option>
             <option value="pm">pm</option>            
        </select>  
        <label for="endTime">End Time:</label>
        <select id ="endTime" >
            <optgroup label="End Time">
              <option value="01:00:00">01:00</option>
              <option value="02:00:00">02:00</option>
              <option value="03:00:00">03:00</option>              
              <option value="04:00:00" selected>04:00</option>
              <option value="05:00:00">05:00</option>
              <option value="06:00:00">06:00</option>
              <option value="07:00:00">07:00</option>
              <option value="08:00:00">08:00</option>
              <option value="09:00:00">09:00</option>
              <option value="10:00:00">10:00</option>
              <option value="11:00:00">11:00</option>
              <option value="12:00:00">12:00</option>
            </optgroup>
          </select>
         <select id="endStatus">
             <option value="am">am</option>
             <option value="pm" selected>pm</option>            
        </select> 
        <div class = "buttons">
           <input type="submit" value="Submit">
           <input type="reset">
        </div>
   </form>  
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You do not have the correct syntax for `switch`. When using it, each `case` is compared to the value you've given, so `switch(foo) { case "X": /* ... */ case "Y": /* ... */case "Z": /* ... */}` is the same as writing `if(foo === "X"} else if (foo === "Y") else if (foo === "Z")`. However, since you have `switch(startTime)` then the value of `case startTime =='01:00:00'` will be compared to `startTime`. That can never match because `startTime =='01:00:00'` will produce `true` or `false` but neither of those values is going to be equal to `startTime` which would be a time string.

Comment: `case startTime =='01:00:00':` must be `case '01:00:00':`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some syntax issue in the above code.

```
   switch(startTime){
        case '01:00:00':
            startTime = '13:00:00'
            break;
        case '02:00:00':
            startTime = '14:00:00'
            break;
        case '03:00:00':
            startTime = '15:00:00'
            break;    
        case '04:00:00':
            startTime = '16:00:00'
            break;     
        case '05:00:00':
            startTime = '17:00:00'
            break; 
        case '06:00:00':
            startTime = '18:00:00'
            break; 
        case '07:00:00':
            startTime = '19:00:00'
            break;
        case '08:00:00':
            startTime = '20:00:00'
            break;
        case '09:00:00':
            startTime = '21:00:00'
            break;    
        case '10:00:00':
            startTime = '22:00:00'
            break;     
        case '11:00:00':
            startTime = '23:00:00'
            break; 
        case '12':
            startTime = '24:00:00'
            break;                
    }



    switch(endTime){
        case '01:00:00':
            endTime = '13:00:00'
            break;
        case '02:00:00':
            endTime = '14:00:00'
            break;
        case '03:00:00':
            endTime = '15:00:00'
            break;    
        case '04:00:00':
            endTime = '16:00:00'
            break;     
        case '05:00:00':
            endTime = '17:00:00'
            break; 
        case '06:00:00':
            endTime = '18:00:00'
            break; 
        case '07:00:00':
            endTime = '19:00:00'
            break;
        case '08:00:00':
            endTime = '20:00:00'
            break;
        case '09:00:00':
            endTime = '21:00:00'
            break;    
        case '10:00:00':
            endTime = '22:00:00'
            break;     
        case '11:00:00':
            endTime = '23:00:00'
            break; 
        case '12':
            endTime = '24:00:00'
            break;                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a syntax error in your `switch`.
Try it like this:
(Look close at `case`).

```js
if (startStatus == 'pm') {
  switch (startTime) {
    case '01:00:00':
      startTime = '13:00:00'
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is just a syntax error, you should not use `case startTime == '09:00:00':` but `case '09:00:00':`